# JTA transactions do not get committed or rollback -- JBossTS, Arjuna

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta, jbossts

I am trying to setup JTA standalone using JBossTs as there is a need to update two data sources. However, the basic functionality of Transaction is not working.

In simple terms, if my DAO attempts to insert two records and second one fails, the first one is still getting committed in the database.

My DAO:

narayana-jta : 4.17.43.Final
org.springframework: 5.1.7.RELEASE
hibernate-core: 5.3.10.Final

```
public void insertRow2(String name, String model) {

    try {
        getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {

                // the table has a primary key on columns MODEL and NAME
                // First call to the method works and this hard-coded row 
                // is inserted.

                // CASE1: In the second call, rec1 saveOrUpdate throws exception and nothing is
                // inserted.

                // CASE2: If the inputs in the method violate the PRIMARY KEY ON table, 
                // and rec1 does not, rec1 still gets inserted, instead of the entire
                // transaction getting rolled back
                TestJTARecord rec1 = new TestJTARecord();
                rec1.setModel("model1");
                rec1.setName("name1");
                session.saveOrUpdate(rec1);


                TestJTARecord rec = new TestJTARecord();
                rec.setModel(model);
                rec.setName(name);
                session.saveOrUpdate(rec);
                session.flush();
                return rec.getModelId();
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("INSERTROW2");
    }

}
```

LOG:

```
2019-06-20 12:50:54,783 DEBUG  org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager Creating new transaction with name [xxxServiceImpl.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-java.lang.Exception [getTransaction:372 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,783 DEBUG  org.hibernate.SQL select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual [logStatement:94 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,805 DEBUG  org.hibernate.SQL select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual [logStatement:94 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,807 DEBUG  org.hibernate.SQL insert into TESTJTA (model, name, modelid) values (?, ?, ?) [logStatement:94 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,812 TRACE  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [model1] [bind:65 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,813 TRACE  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [name1] [bind:65 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,813 TRACE  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [14501] [bind:65 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,820 DEBUG  org.hibernate.SQL insert into TESTJTA (model, name, modelid) values (?, ?, ?) [logStatement:94 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,821 TRACE  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [test2] [bind:65 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,821 TRACE  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [test1] [bind:65 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,821 TRACE  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [14502] [bind:65 {}] 
2019-06-20 12:50:54,822 ERROR  xxxServiceImpl ========> EXCEPTION CAUGHT [error:240 {}] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: INSERTROW2
    at xxxDAOImpl.insertRow2(xxxDAOImpl.java:199) ~[xxx.jar:?]
    at xxxServiceImpl.save(xxxServiceImpl.java:84) ~[xxx.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) [spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.save(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]

2019-06-20 12:50:54,823 DEBUG  org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager Initiating transaction rollback [processRollback:836 {}] 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: INSERTROW2
    at xxxDAOImpl.insertRow2(xxxDAOImpl.java:199) ~[xxx.jar:?]
    at xxxServiceImpl.save(xxxServiceImpl.java:84) ~[xxx.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.save(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    ... 9 more
```

It seems to appear that each SQL statment executed by the DAO is in a separate transaction instead of the entire method. Also, calling flush() or not does not seem to have any affect.

The same code works as expected if I use HibernateTransactionManager.

```
<bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager" factory-method="transactionManager" id="arjunaTransactionManager" />
    <bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction" factory-method="userTransaction" id="arjunaUserTransaction" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="arjunaTransactionManager" />
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="arjunaUserTransaction" />
    </bean>
```

Date source

```
<bean id="testJTA" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName">
       <value>com.arjuna.ats.jdbc.TransactionalDriver</value>
      </property>
      <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>

      <property name="username">
            <value>testjta</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>testjta</value>
        </property>
  </bean>
```

Hibernate Config

```
<bean id="testJTASessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <description>
            Hibernate session support bean. Additional mappings go into mappingResources list.
        </description>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="testJTA"/>
        <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
               <value>hibernate/TestJTA.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">3</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.flushMode">COMMIT</prop> -->

                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jta.allowTransactionAccess">true</prop>
                </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Update 1:
Using `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource` and setting `defaultAutoCommit=false` does not work as nothing gets committed in the database. Don't see any errors. If I execute the method again, exception are thrown saying unique constraint violated but the table in DB is empty. It seems, JTA transaction's commit or rollback does not seem to have any affect.

Update 2: With above change, the SQL are being executed but nothing gets committed.  If I execute the code again, I get SQL unique constraint exception but table in DB is empty.

Comment: Have you configured hibernate appropriatly for JTA? Show the hibernate configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated the question with Hibernate configuration. Thanks.

Comment: THat looks ok, one thing though is that the `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't an XA capable datasource and for JTA to work you will need an XA capable datasource. You probably need to wrap it in another one to make it XA capable.

Comment: @M.Deinum OK. I picked it up from the examples on using JBossTS. Let me try if I can set it up using `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource`

Comment: @@M.Deinum. Used the `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource` and was able to setup the datasource. I see the same behavior. However, if I get the connection from Session and set autocommit=false, then first save does not get committed if second fails.  I am now testing by setting `defaultAutoCommit` of `XADataSource` to false.

Comment: I would suspect you need to use a Naryana wrapper to make it aware of the tx setup. Normally you would setup things in JNDI so that auto register. Now you need to manually do all the setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am trying to setup JTA outside the App server so, cannot use JNDI.

Comment: Then make sure you do setup everything correctly, you currently are missing things. Also do you really want/need to use JTA? You can still use local transactions and compensate if something goes wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum Eventually, I have to deal with multiple data-sources.

Comment: @dRv I recommend to consider some new version of Narayana if really you don't need to stuck with 4.17.x release. The 5.x gained several enhancements in transaction processing and the 5.9.x.Final is part of the WildFly distribution without any known issue.

Comment: @dRv Then, check the Narayana quickstarts on spring integration - https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/tree/master/spring. There could be points that help you to create your own setup correctly. I would highlight that besides the right integration of the Narayana transaction manager with Spring framework you should consider setting up the recovery processing as well.